# Splitting Training Data to train optimal number of n models

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

lets assume we have a huge Database providing us with the training data D and a dedicated smaller testing data T for a machine learning problem. 
The data covers many aspects of a real world problem and thus is very diverse in its structure. 
When we now train a not closer defined machine learning algorithm (Neural Network, SVM, Random Forest, ...) with D and finally test the created model against T we obtain a certain performance measure P (confusion matrix, mse, ...).

The Question: If I could achieve a better performance, by dividing the problem ito smaller sub-problems, e.g. by clustering D into several distinct training sets D1, D2, D3, ..., how could I find the optimal clusters? (number of clusters, centroids,...)

In a brute-force fashion I am thinking about using a kNN Clustering with a random number of clusters C, which leads to the training data D1, D2,...Dc. 
I would now train C different models and finally test them against the training sets T1, T2, ..., Tc, where the same kNN Clustering has been used to split T into the C test sets T1,..,Tc.

The combination which gives me the best overall performance mean(P1,P2,...,Pc) would be the one I would like to choose.

I was just wondering whether you know a more sophisticated way than brute-forcing this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: That does not make much sense. Try to be more formal on what you are doing. It currently sounds like: split some huge data into smaller ones by kNN which effects in very different datasets; learn some classifier on each of these and take the best. Obviously this is near the worst approach possible as generalization is killed. Randomly chosing the datasets would be better (no kNN).

Comment: Randomly chosing datasets is what e.g. random forest does, and I am aware of its benefits. But anyways, splitting a big problem into sub-problems should make the sub-problem handling easier. You are right, the single modle are much worse in generalization, as the are ment to deal only with a small subset of the whole possibility space. Thats why it is very important to have a good preselection step, which is able to correctly cluster new incoming data.

Comment: Imaging a problem, where different pieces of cloth should be distinguished. Trousers from shirts, dresses from suits and so on. Now each of the different categories has sub-categories. Trousers can be distinguished in jeans, cort, suit trousers etc. Instead of learning the whole data, I could have a single model for trousers only, whose reduced problem is now to distinguish jeans from cort etc. Now it is very important to have a preprocessing step which can distinguish trousers from the rest. And only if I am already sure it is trousers, I use the trousers model.

Comment: You are mixing a lot of different concepts here. The only thing i can say for sure: you are somewhat shifting an easier problem (e.g. SVM: convex -> P if approximated) to a harder problem (clustering; NP-hard).

Comment: There is no kNN clustering, only kNN classification or k-means clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is hard.

Much harder than classification, because you don't have labels to tell you if you are doing okay, or not well at all. It can't do magic, but it requires you to carefully choose parameters and evaluate the result.

You cannot just dump your data into k-means and expect anything useful to come out. You'd first need to really really carefully clean and preprocess your data, and then you might simply figure out that it actually is only *one* single large clump...

Furthermore, if clustering worked well and you train classifiers on each cluster independently, then every classifier will miss crucial data. The result will likely performing really really bad!

If you want to only train on parts of the data, use a random forest.

But it sounds like you are more interested in a hierarchical classification approach. That may work, if you have good hierarchy information. You'd first train a classifier on the category, then another within the category only to get the final class.